# C++ factorial function not working

Tags: c++, factorial

Can someone please help me understand why this code isn't working properly? I know it's very close and I think that I'm just overlooking something. Any help is appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #define TEST_ARRAY_SIZE 4

    long int factorial(int num);

    long int factorial(int num){
        for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        num *= i;
        }
            return num;
    }

    int main() {
        int test[TEST_ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 5, 7};
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TEST_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            std::cout << "Factorial of " << test[i] << " is " << factorial(test[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You might try moving the `return` outside the loop. Fixing your indentation would help make that more obvious. But that will also make your loop infinite, since you're modifying the variable you're using as your loop termination.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `return num;` outside the loop. As it is now, control always return after the first number is multiplied.

-- the correct code --

```
long int factorial(int num){
    long int res = 1; 
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    res *= i;
    }
return res;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but it still isn't outputting the correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

The body of the factorial function is not correct. You can use a recursive method to compute the factorial of a specific number. The corrected program of your version is below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #define TEST_ARRAY_SIZE 4

    long int factorial(int num);

    int main() {

       int test[TEST_ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 5, 7};

       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TEST_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
           std::cout << "Factorial of " << test[i] << " is " << factorial(test[i]) << std::endl;
       }

       return 0;
    }

    long int factorial(int num){
       if (num == 1)
          return num;
       else
          return num * factorial(num-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's only part of the problem; it's a case in which proper indentation would make the bug apparent in an instant.

In addition to that, why are you using num inside the loop? You should leave it as-is and declare a new variable to compound and return the result.

```
long int factorial(unsigned int num) {
   int x = 1;

   for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      x *= i;
   }

   return x;
}
```

Other things to note:

- You shouldn't be using a #define; you should declare a const instead.
- You're comparing an unsigned against a signed in the factorial() for loop.